# Can we retrieve the Text value of DDL using Hidden Field option code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

using hidden field option in code behind.

Functionality for DDL selection is written in JQuery and assigned its value to hidden field. Now i want the text value where it is returning the index.

Comment: Make the hidden field a server control `<asp:Hidden...` and you can retrieve the value. The question is a little hard to understand. What have you tried?

Comment: can you please help me with the code snippet.

Comment: i have written the Functionality for DDL in Jquery and i want to use the same in code behind. suppose selected value in DDL is "ABC" which i want in code behind , it is returning me the index of the value eg:1

Comment: can you add your code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

if you have HTML like this

```
<select id="YourDropDownSelectId" name="Name" onchange="SetSelectedText(this)">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id = "Yourinputid" name="InputName" />
```

You can add below by adding to asp page

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
function SetSelectedText(YourDropDownSelectId) {
    var selectedText = YourDropDownSelectId.options[YourDropDownSelectId.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("Yourinputid").value = selectedText;
}
</script>
```

and then retrieve using code behind like this inside your event handler

```
 string Value = Request.Form["InputName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

when i try to debug it is getting assigned by all the values of DDL as below. I need only one value get assigned.[image]